# How to modify core product block

Tags: product, blocks, view

I have a problem with having any impact on how the site render a block. I want to pass data about shipping price to a product page, and I want it done by creating module, I've made standard: `app/code/me/mymodule/etc/di.xml`, `app/code/me/mymodule/etc/module.xml`, `registration.php`, and `View.php` In which I wanted to extend core class and override method `getProductPrice` from `AbstractProduct` class. It is supposed to concatenate original html too but now I want to focus on having anything work, and it doesn't, the file is loading because I get errors when I try to add constructor but I don't need it anyway. Any suggestions? I would appreciate too if someone would tell if it is correct approach or not.

```
<?php
namespace me\MyModule;
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
  {
   public function getProductPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
  {
     return "<h1>Thats something</h1>";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Plugin to do this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
        <plugin name="customParams"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Block\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>

app/code/Company/Module/Model/Plugin/Block/Product.php
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin\Block;

class Product
{
    public function afterGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
    {
        //Your custom code here
    }
}
```